# Code doesn't return float

Tags: python

The code returns `4.0` for input `([4 ,5 ,5 ,4])` and it should return `4.5` and it divides `4/5`.
How can I fix this?
Edit: I am trying to find the median of a list.

```
    def median(lis):
    srt_list = lis
    srt_list.sort()
    new_lis = srt_list[0:len(lis)//2]
    new_lis_last = srt_list[len(lis)//2:]
    if len(srt_list) % 2 == 0:
        lst_index = new_lis[len(new_lis)-1]
        frs_index = new_lis_last[0]
        med = (frs_index + lst_index) / 2.0
        print med  
    else:
        frs_index = new_lis_last[0]
print median([7,3,1,4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `//` floor division. If you wanted to use *float* division instead, use `/`:

```
med = (frs_index) + lst_index) / 2.0
```

There is no need to convert `2.0` into a float, it *already* is a floating point literal.

Note that the following will sort `lis` in place:

```
srt_list = lis
srt_list.sort()
```

`srt_list` is another reference to the same list object, *not* a copy.

The code:

```
for i in range(len(new_lis)):
    lst_index = new_lis[len(new_lis)-1]
    return float(lst_index)
    break
```

ignores the list index as it just returns `float(new_lis[-1])`; you may as well drop the loops here. Everything after the `return` is not going to be executed as the function is exited at that point.

This applies to all 3 loops; it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with these loops.

Answer (score 4):

You are using floor division operator (`//`) in

```
med = (frs_index) + lst_index) // float(2.0)
```

Change it to use `/`, like this

```
med = (frs_index) + lst_index) / float(2.0)
```

**Example:**

```
print 5/2.0    # 2.5
print 5//2.0   # 2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Even you should use `/` and not `//`, you are never reaching your división:

```
med = (frs_index) + lst_index) // float(2.0)
```

because your 2 for loops have a return statement inside:

```
    for i in range(len(new_lis)):
        lst_index = new_lis[len(new_lis)-1]
        return float(lst_index) # If arriving here, you function return new_lis[len(new_lis)-1] and finish
        break
    for i in range(len(new_lis_last)):
        frs_index = new_lis_last[0]
        return float(frs_index) # If arriving here, you function return new_lis_last[0] and finish
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is correct that in

```
med = (frs_index) + lst_index) // float(2.0)
```

you should replace `//` by `/` that is not the reason why you get `4.0` instead of `4.5`

The way you have written the code, most of your logic does not get executed.

```
if len(srt_list) % 2 == 0:
    #print "even"
    for i in range(len(new_lis)):
        lst_index = new_lis[len(new_lis)-1]
        return float(lst_index) #This is hit and returns
        break
```

Broadly what your code does is splits the list and if the first list is even lengthed, returns the float representation of the first element. I am sure this is not what you want to do.